# Remove file extension for specific page(s) with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove the file extension (in this case .php) for specific files only on my website. I'd like the page to display without the extension when someone visits a link to said page.

For example, I'd like www.mysite.com/calendar.php to display as www.mysite.com/calendar, while visiting the homepage would remain as www.mysite.com/index.php

The catch is that I only want this to work for *specific pages* on the site, and not the entire site.

I've tried a few variations that I've found (some here, some from external sites) and none seem to work properly.

This example:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /calendar.php to /calendar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(calendar)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward calendar to calendar.php
RewriteRule ^(calendar)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

doesn't seem to force the page over to the url without the extension (www.mysite.com/calendar). However, just visiting www.mysite.com/calendar works fine.

The next example:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /calendar.php to /calendar
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} calendar.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /calendar [L,R=302,NC]

# To internally forward calendar to calendar.php
RewriteRule ^(calendar)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

seems to work for getting the url to display without the extension, but results in a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error, as it seems to be looping.

I feel like I'm close, but can't quite get this to work correctly. I'd ideally like to be able to do this for a handful of pages on the site.

***EDIT***

As anubhava suggested in the comments, I updated the first example to:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /calendar.php to /calendar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(calendar)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /q90fm-2017/calendar [L,R=302,NC]

# To internally forward calendar to calendar.php
RewriteRule ^(calendar)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

and now it works perfectly!

Comment: Try: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(calendar)\.php[\s?] [NC]`

Comment: @anubhava Worked beautifully! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating my comment to answer so that it can help someone facing similar problem.

Issue is that this .htaccess is inside a sub-directory and not directly under site root. That is the reason `\s/+` is not matching in `RewriteCond` above.

I suggest following rule that avoids hardcoding sub-directory as well:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /calendar.php to /calendar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/*(\S*?/calendar)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To internally forward calendar to calendar.php
RewriteRule ^(calendar)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```